# Time and date from shadow

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, mathematical-astronomy

Given longitude, latitude and the height of a vertical stick at sea level, is it possible to determine date and time from the direction and length of its shadow? If yes, what are the formulas?

Comment: There are at least two days during the year that will give you the same results.

Comment: There's also one more piece of information necessary: bearing. If you don't know which way is north, the direction of the shadow won't be useful.